# URI not registered error in Intellij IDEA for if and unless namespaces in Ant plugin

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ant

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA with Ant plugin.
I want to use conditional tasks in my `build.xml` file, so I added this code to `project` root tag:

```
xmlns:if="ant:if" xmlns:unless="ant:unless"
```

but Intellij IDEA shows error with "URI not registered" message. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a known bug, feel free to vote:

- [IDEA-140837](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-140837) Ant syntax check does not recognize xmlns:if="ant:if" and xmlns:unless="ant:unless"